# How to release an Android app update for specific countries on Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play, release-management

I have an Android app on the Play Store that is available for 3 countries A, B, and C. And I want to release an update for countries A & B only, and country C sees only the current version and not the update.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is outside the scope described by the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: The question is about a tool that programmers use, which is mentioned in the top of the help center link you provided!

Comment: Hello @y.allam, please refer to item 7 of the list within the linked page (beginning, "Questions asking for support for offsite resources such as App Stores are off-topic for Stack Overflow").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used it before, but when you make a release you can select the target countries for the release right after uploading your APK in the last review step like in the image below!

[image]